# 404 error Tomcat App

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I know there is similar questions but this one is strange and has me stuck.

My Java servlet will run in Eclipse interface using the Tomcat server and my SoapUI tests bring back the expected responses.  However, when I deploy the servlet and run Tomcat and enter a SoapUI test I receive a 404 error.

Can someone explain why this is please?  I have tried specifying the WSDL in both the Eclipse environment and the deployed WAR.

Thanks in advance for assistance

AJF

Comment: Did you read the logs?

Comment: Yes.  Catalina log does not tell me any thing except the usual noted during Tomcat start up and shutdown.  The Local access log only states one line shown below (Management insist I do not show IP Address or app name).  The line is - MyIPAddress - - [12/Dec/2013:12:19:32 +0000] "POST /appname/SwiftChildServicePort HTTP/1.1" 404 1036

Comment: Yes.  Tomcat is starting using the startup.bat file.  The output to the console window looks normal for startup and after startup I can go to http://localhost:8080/ and the Tomcat home page is shown in the browser.

Comment: However, just noticed that if I click on the "Manager App" button on the Tomcat home page, it does not offer a credentials login but instead goes straight to a page stating "HTTP Status 404 - /manager/html".  Never experienced this before.